# The chess.com engine didn’t show a checkmate

Tags: checkmate, pawns, en-passant

I've attached a screen shot of my game. It is Black’s turn to move. Their king was under check, but not checkmate, as the website didn't show mate.

[image]

After awhile, Black had to resign due to not being able to make any valid move.  Analyzing the game with a computer results in the move 41. gxh3 being suggested.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As White's previous move was pawn on h2 to h4 then pawn g4xh3 is a legal en passant capture.

For more info - see Rule 3.7.d of [the laws of chess](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article)

Comment: Useful explanation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMgIKo2GM6M